# Identify: comic book about an astronaut

Tags: story-identification, comics, space-exploration

10-15 years ago I read a comic book about an astronaut. As far as I remember the action begin on Earth right after some kind of war or conflict with alien race. Main hero is young or middle aged man who works as astronaut. He is traveling through space and due to some physics factors (speed? gravity?) his time passes slower than on Earth. I don't remember too much, just few scenes:

1. He goes back on earth and someone from his family (maybe mother, not sure) is dying, he can't get any medicines due to some regime policy, he is trying to buy it on black market or something like that.
2. He lose his limbs and he is on some "spa"-like planet where it grows back.
3. Some people in future don't have sex (maybe they are androids?).
4. I'm not sure how many years it takes (the action) but I think it may be like 300-1000 years from the beginning to the end, I think it was more than one book.

Answer (score 12):

This might be the [comic book version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War_%28comics%29) of Haldemans "Forever War". Matching plot points are at least a war with aliens, time dilation, regrown limbs on a paradise planet and while the people in the future do have sex it's not for reproduction (homosexuality is encouraged to combat overpopulation). It's from 1988 so you might have read it 15 years ago.

Comment: yeah, thats it! Thanks Eike!

Comment: If the answer was helpful you might consider to "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to the left.